# Xcode 5 incredibly slow with OSX Mavericks despite 16GB RAM and Quad-Core

Tags: xcode

I have updated quite a while ago to OSX Mavericks on my Mac book pro 15 inch with quad-core i7 processor and 16GB of RAM. Xcode is so slow the coloured wheel spins as soon as I try to scroll down on a code page, or when I try to edit the code. It is impossible to work with it. Even slower if I am running the app on an IOS device while I am using it. I have re-intalled both Mavericks and Xcode but there is no change in performance. How can I solve this terrible and frustrating issue?

EDIT TOP TEST:

Processes: 208 total, 2 running, 3 stuck, 203 sleeping, 927 threads    19:04:32
Load Avg: 1.49, 1.23, 1.09  CPU usage: 3.96% user, 3.6% sys, 92.97% idle
SharedLibs: 16M resident, 16M data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 39985 total, 2267M resident, 128M private, 1038M shared.
PhysMem: 5913M used (1771M wired), 10G unused.
VM: 497G vsize, 1065M framework vsize, 0(0) swapins, 0(0) swapouts.
Networks: packets: 56398/45M in, 41617/6907K out.
Disks: 243504/3289M read, 144828/2409M written.

PID   COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT #MREG MEM    RPRVT  PURG
2458  syncdefaults 0.0  00:00.40 9     5    102   84    5136K  3948K  0B
2457  top          9.3  00:01.71 1/1   0    23    40    2220K  1992K  0B
2454  bash         0.0  00:00.01 1     0    19    30    616K   452K   0B
2453  com.apple.au 0.0  00:00.04 2     1    47    60    1636K  948K   0B
2452  login        0.0  00:00.08 2     0    30    50    1120K  792K   0B
2451  com.apple.au 0.0  00:00.01 2     1    31    50    1280K  732K   0B
2449  Terminal     25.4 00:01.35 10    4    187   150   9444K+ 6380K+ 8192B
2448  QuickLookSat 0.0  00:00.18 2     0    50    76    3044K  1872K  0B
2447  quicklookd   0.0  00:00.12 5     1    86    87    4120K  2824K  0B
2446  mdworker     0.0  00:00.12 3     0    52    73    3168K  2208K  0B
2445  CVMCompiler  0.0  00:00.01 2     1    31    43    2268K  1968K  8192B
2443  launchd      0.0  00:00.00 2     0    62    38    628K   580K   0B
2440  ocspd        0.0  00:00.02 2     0    25    40    1132K  696K   0B
2431  com.apple.ap 0.0  00:06.57 3     0    223   345   29M    17M    8192B

Comment: By the way, no other programs are running at the same time

Comment: sorry I don't get what your talking about. Excuse my ignorance, what is nano and make?

Comment: @H2CO3, I have the same system as the OP (MBP Retina i7 quad, 16GB RAM, Mavericks) and Xcode 5 is super zippy for me...no issues. So I would consider his problem abnormal.

Comment: @Alessandro, he's talking about command-line tools (that you can run in Terminal.app) that he uses for text editing and compiling his source code, instead of using a graphical IDE like Xcode. It comes down to personal preference.

Comment: No I wound need a solution for Xcode, and as @jrodatus the issue is not normal, it shouldn't be like this

Comment: I have a similarly configured MBP as @jrodatus, no performance problems at all.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of wheat are the causes or any solution to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running "top" in the Terminal to see whether it is actually the Xcode process hogging the CPU or some hidden subtask?

Comment: no, i'll do it now, so only 'top'

Comment: see results in answer

Comment: Your TOP paste is incredibly hard to read, but I don't see anything wrong there. Sometimes, my Xcode 5 also gets inexplicably slow. Restarting it or the machine fixes it. BTW, I don't think this is the correct site for the question.

Comment: This is about a performance problem with running the IDE (on a Mac). Wouldn't it belong on Ask Different?